# The university bestowed an honorary degree on her (vs. to her)

Tags: word-usage, prepositions, sentence-choice

> The university bestowed an honorary degree on her. (O)

> The university bestowed an honorary degree to her. (X)

If 'to' is not used, why it is not used?

When you use 'on' instead of 'for/to' as in the sentence above?

PS. As a non-native speaker, 'of' is the same kind of thing. I am familiar with 'for' or 'to' but uncomfortable when it comes to 'of' or 'on'

Comment: Both of these are awkward and sound non-native. Sorry. I wouldn't use the verb bestowed. This is better "The University awarded her an honorary degree".

Answer (score 2):

**The simple answer:**

`To` is not used, because the word is `bestowed upon/on`. That's just how the word works.

**The more complex answer (which is just a hypothesis):**

`Bestow` comes from `stow`, which is a synonym for `place`. So by bestowing the honorary degree, the university literally places it **on** the person.